# How can I modify the strings of a binary(Mach-O) file?

Tags: executable, mach-o

Is there any way to (easily) modify a string in a Mach-O binary? I want to extend the length of a pre-existing string.

Answer (score 0):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/machoview

Extending the string will not be an easy task with manual editing, but at least you can get a picture about the Mach-O file structure.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be an easy procedure, you cannot just go and change a string in textedit and hope it works because mach-o binaries work with encoded bytes and if 1 byte is out of order, the binary will not be executed properly. If you really wish to modify a string inside a fully assembled mach-o binary file without disrupting its delicate code you will need lots of knowledge and understanding of how mach binaries work. You will need to be able to modify it in single bytes and replacing its encoded numbers and offsets. [Hopper](http://hopperapp.com) for Mac might be able to help you understand the architecture of a mach-o binary. but if you need to replace a string with a different string with the exact same length, you might be able to simply replace its bytes so that the binary still reads it at the same length. but you will need a hexadecimal modifying application to do that.